# Render block in front of flex-items

Tags: html, css

I want the red box to be rendered in front of the following flex items, but nothing I tried leads to this sort of order.

```css
.box {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.front .box {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.back {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <div class="box yellow">
    <div class="box red" style="position:block; margin-left: 50px; z-index: 99999">2</div></div>
  <div class="box green">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no `position:block`

Comment: maybe I chose a bad minimal example, cause it did not work, I've already tryed this approach *sadface

Comment: so edit your question to include a better minimal example. Actually your only issue a miss use of position property

Comment: I finally found the issue, the property overflow hidden was active, this lead to a hidden element and no z-index would work. Thank you all for your support

Answer (score 2):

Change it from `position: block` to `position: absolute`. There is no `position: block`, and you must use a proper positioning attribute to get `z-index` to work properly.

```css
.box {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.front .box {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.back {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <div class="box yellow">
    <div class="box red" style="position:absolute; margin-left: 50px; z-index: 99999">2</div></div>
  <div class="box green">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: or `relative` also

Answer (score 1):

First thing I noticed was `position:block` which is actually wrong, `position` can basically be `absolute`  or `relative`.  And I strongly believe you could have put the inline styles in the `.red` CSS selector. To answer your question of putting the red box in front what you need is `order` property which has effect only on flex items so for example if you has

```
.green{
background: green;
order: -1;
}
```

The green box will be further to the left than the red box.
Normally in the natural ordering all flex items has an order of zero (0) so give an item a negative other will move it further to the left until it gets to an element which is also a flex item that has a lesser order value.
I noticed your red box doesn't have a height though or I omitted it accidentally while I was typing it in #happyCoding